# Идентификация клиента приложения

Tags: java, android

Как идентифицировать пользователя приложения? 
К примеру: Марка телефона + IP не являются уникальными. Как это делает Firebase? Как они идентифицируют пользователя и создают для него уникальный токен?

Comment: Идентифицировать где? О каком Firebase-токене речь?

Comment: Идентифицировать на сервере. Мне необходимо отправить на сервер уникальный идентификатор пользователя, который использует приложение. Firebase создает уникальный token для каждого пользователя приложения. Как они прежде, чем создать токен идентифицируют пользователя? По IMEI?

Comment: Судя по всему, а) это неизвестно, б) далеко не факт, что у одного пользователя идентификатор постоянный https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38760612/how-does-firebase-generate-the-uid

Comment: первое что пришло в голову: при первом запуске приложения создаем в памяти приложения файлик с навзанием "текущая дата + рандомизатор". это и будет личный ID. правда если удалить приложение - оно удалится. при обновлении такого не будет.